Koltin Hibernate doesent work in jar. Throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
I am starting Hibernate inside my Minecraft plugin.
class ChatListener(
) : Listener {

    private val sessionFactory: SessionFactory by lazy {
        Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()
    }

    @EventHandler
    fun onPlayerChat(event: PlayerChatEvent) {
        val playerUUID = "1234"  // This should be dynamically obtained from the event or player

        sessionFactory.openSession().use { session ->
            val playerEntity = session.get(McPlayerEntity::class.java, playerUUID)
            if (playerEntity != null) {
                event.player.sendMessage("Player UUID: ${playerEntity.playerUUID}, Rank: ${playerEntity.rang}")
            } else {
                event.player.sendMessage("Player not found.")
            }
        }
    }
}

but iam getting this error :
[13:36:54 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling Paper-Kotlin-Template v1.0.0 (Is it up to date?)
org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:132) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:66) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:57) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:244) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:397) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:382) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/gg.flyte.template.PluginTemplate.onEnable(PluginTemplate.kt:15) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:288) ~[paper-api-1.20.6-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginInstanceManager.enablePlugin(PaperPluginInstanceManager.java:202) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.enablePlugin(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:109) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:520) ~[paper-api-1.20.6-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:626) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:575) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadWorld0(MinecraftServer.java:675) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadLevel(MinecraftServer.java:437) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:323) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1136) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:323) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[?:?]
Caused by: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of Jakarta XML Binding-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:250) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:238) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:386) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:605) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:546) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:121) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.ContextFactory
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[?:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:113) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:146) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:238) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:386) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:605) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:546) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.JaxbCfgProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbCfgProcessor.java:121) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        ... 18 more
[13:36:54 INFO]: [Paper-Kotlin-Template] Disabling Paper-Kotlin-Template v1.0.0
[13:36:54 ERROR]: Error occurred while disabling Paper-Kotlin-Template v1.0.0
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property sessionFactory has not been initialized
        at Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar/gg.flyte.template.PluginTemplate.onDisable(PluginTemplate.kt:21) ~[Paper-Kotlin-Template-all.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:291) ~[paper-api-1.20.6-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginInstanceManager.disablePlugin(PaperPluginInstanceManager.java:237) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.disablePlugin(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:114) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:550) ~[paper-api-1.20.6-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginInstanceManager.enablePlugin(PaperPluginInstanceManager.java:206) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.enablePlugin(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:109) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:520) ~[paper-api-1.20.6-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:626) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:575) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadWorld0(MinecraftServer.java:675) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadLevel(MinecraftServer.java:437) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:323) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1136) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:323) ~[paper-1.20.6.jar:1.20.6-149-6e71f41]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[?:?]

here is my hibernate.cfg.xml :
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <mapping class="gg.flyte.template.McPlayerEntity"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>


here is my build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "2.0.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt") version "1.8.0"
    id("org.hibernate.orm") version "6.3.0.Final"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/") {
        name = "papermc-repo"
    }
    maven("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/") {
        name = "sonatype"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly("io.papermc.paper:paper-api:1.20.6-R0.1-SNAPSHOT")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.6.0.Final")
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33")
    kapt("org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.6.0.Final")
    implementation("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.24.0")

    // Jakarta XML Binding (JAXB)
    implementation("org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.5")
    implementation("jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0")
    implementation("jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:4.0.2")
}
val targetJavaVersion = 21
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(targetJavaVersion)
}
tasks.processResources {
    val props = mapOf("version" to version)
    inputs.properties(props)
    filteringCharset = "UTF-8"
    filesMatching("paper-plugin.yml") {
        expand(props)
    }
}

When I run Hibernate directly in IntelliJ, everything works perfectly, but it fails when I run it in the JAR file. What could be causing this? I've looked at other Stack Overflow questions, but I haven't found a solution. Here is the main code that works when I run it in IntelliJ:
fun main() {
    // Hibernate-Konfiguration und SessionFactory erstellen
    val sessionFactory: SessionFactory = Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()

    sessionFactory.openSession().use { session ->
        // Beispiel-UUID eines Spielers (muss existieren)
        val playerUUID = "1234"

        // Den Spieler aus der Datenbank holen
        val playerEntity = session.get(McPlayerEntity::class.java, playerUUID)

        // Überprüfen, ob der Spieler gefunden wurde
        if (playerEntity != null) {
            println("Spieler UUID: ${playerEntity.playerUUID}, Rang: ${playerEntity.rang}")
        } else {
            println("Spieler nicht gefunden.")
        }
    }

    // Schließen der SessionFactory
    sessionFactory.close()
}

I built the jar with shadowjar ->  id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
